# How is this Chinese character with boxes in the background font achieved on iOS?

Tags: fonts, typography, ios

I was wondering how this text effect was achieved? The characters appear with boxes behind them on desktop versions as well (this is from Instagram) and i’m wondering how this was achieved and where I might be able to recreate it. The characters still register as Chinese characters in every context but they also have the box behind them.

[image: Text effect in question.]

Comment: What don't you understand about a box drawn and placed behind a character? Are you asking for software to create it?  Just about any graphics software could be used

Comment: @Billy I think the OP is wanting to know how to create actual glyphs in the font file with squares like this?

Comment: @ZachSaucier - Perhaps, however that's why I'm asking for more information and clarity.

Comment: These are characters being used on someone’s Instagram page, I’m asking if anyone knows how this would have been achieved on iOS as the characters fully register as Chinese yet they have the boxes behind them. It appears to be a standard Unicode(?) font or something because it’s displayed correctly on my phone and on my desktop and I’m wondering how it was achieved.

Comment: @高校生 It can be (and if it’s in an iOS app, possibly was) done using simple CSS.

Comment: If these are raster image on an Instagram post, then virtually any graphics program capable of drawing boxes and typing characters could have been used. Are the characters part of a raster image?

Comment: @BillyKerr No, this was a part of someone's Instagram bio, which means that these are just regular characters such as any characters you may use on an app. 蔡⃣   锦⃣   麟⃣  <- this is a copy and paste of the characters directly from the website.

Comment: 把⃣大⃣爱⃣心⃣送⃣给⃣你⃣们⃣哦⃣！送⃣我⃣小⃣送⃣给⃣我⃣把⃣么⃣么⃣哒⃣

Here are multiple examples from another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is achieved by:

> Simply add Unicode character U+20E3 after the one you want to be enclosed.

Comment: Very good! Just an addition: some typefaces do have a seperate font with boxes around the glyphs, like "Linux libertine". Another possibility would be that the whole font is actually designed with boxes, and that there are no glyphs without boxes. The designers would simply assign the boxed glyph to the Unicode of the unboxed character..